# On browser window resize, 'top' gets set to 0. How to stop it?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a fixed div inside my document. (With css `position: fixed`) I'm calculating its 'top' on resize and setting it, so it appears to be frozen at a particular place according to requirements.

Trouble is, every time I resize, the 'top' gets set to '0px' briefly, before my value is applied. This causes a flicker every time the browser is resized.

Is there any way to stop this behavior of the browser? Or any workaround so my 'top' doesn't get overridden by the browser's?

I'm looking for solutions in javascript only. Can't use jquery.

EDIT:

This is my code. The requirement is to fix a (1000px long) div with a given top and bottom offset. The top offset, say 50px should show the div fixed 50px below the top of the viewport. When you scroll; this offset should be applied; until you reach the bottom; in which case the bottom offset, say 100px is to be applied, which shows the end of the div 50 px from the bottom of the viewport.

Essentially, the fixed div should start 'scrolling' (by changing the `top` when the document scrolls) when the document scrolls past a certain value (when `scrollTop` is more than the sum of the div's height and the offsets).

```
var fixForever = function(){
            var elem = options.elem;
            //elem.style.position = 'fixed';
            //if bottom isn't given, stick to top at all times            
            if(!options.bottom){ 
                //this will return if bottom is null/undefined or '0px'             
                return;
            }
            var topWindow = window.top;
            var docBody = topWindow.document.body;
            var docEl = topWindow.document.documentElement;

            var elemHeight = parseFloat(elem.style.height);
            var topOffset = options.top ? options.top : 0;
            var bottomOffset = options.bottom ? options.bottom : 0;
            var elemHeightPlusOffsets = elemHeight + topOffset + bottomOffset;

            var opt = {};
            opt.elem = elem;
            opt.topOffset = topOffset;
            opt.elemHeightPlusOffsets = elemHeightPlusOffsets;

            moveSideskin(docBody, docEl, opt);

            topWindow.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {                 
                moveSideskin(docBody, docEl, opt);
            });

            var doit;
            topWindow.addEventListener('resize', function (e) { 
                moveSideskin(docBody, docEl, opt);
            });

            function resizeEnd(){
                // Haven't resized in 100ms!            
                moveSideskin(docBody, docEl, opt);

            }
        };

        function moveSideskin(docBody, docEl, opt){
            var topWindow = window.top;
            var scrollTop = docBody.scrollTop || docEl.scrollTop;
            var viewportHeight = topWindow.innerHeight;

            var elem = opt.elem;
            var topOffset = opt.topOffset;
            var elemHeightPlusOffsets = opt.elemHeightPlusOffsets;

            var docHeight = getDocHeight(docBody, docEl);
            var beginScrollingFrom = docHeight - elemHeightPlusOffsets;

            if(scrollTop >= beginScrollingFrom){
                var difference = scrollTop - beginScrollingFrom;
                elem.style.top = topOffset - difference + 'px';
                // this is what should be applied but gets overridden to '0px' on resize

            } else {
                elem.style.top = topOffset + 'px';
            }
        }



        function getDocHeight(docBody, docEl) {
            return Math.max(
                docBody.scrollHeight, docEl.scrollHeight,
                docBody.offsetHeight, docEl.offsetHeight,
                docBody.clientHeight, docEl.clientHeight
            );
        }
```

Comment: Adding your code would be very helpful. Or even better, reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Just wondering, but are you aware of CSS [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)?  May or may not be helpful to you.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I'm aware and I've applied it. The '0px' overrides it.

Comment: @LinkinTED: The code is calculating top according to very specific and calculated reqirements. It'ss do more harm than good. I'll try to reproduce it in a fiddle.

Comment: Without seeing any applicable code, it's going to be hard to try to help in any meaningful way

Comment: @LinkinTED: I've added the code.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I've added the code.